# What's the most efficient way of inserting dynamically loaded JavaScript and CSS into a page?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I've got a site where I need to load JavaScript and CSS files dynamically through AJAX. I've got this working fine, my issue is with loading this content into the DOM, specifically the speed.

In desktop browsers, there's no performance issue. But on mobile browsers (the site is aimed at phones/tablets), there's a good second or two of lag between the script/styles being downloaded and finishing processing.

Originally, I was creating a new script/style element, appending the retrieved data and appending the element to the DOM (the 'head' node).
Then I tried using 'document.write' to write a script/style tag with the content into the page (this is how Bing/Google do it on their mobile site).
Both of these methods are too slow.

Is this likely to be due to the size of the scripts needing to be processed (70KB of JavaScript. 65KB of CSS)? Or is it to do with how I'm inserting in into the page?

I've not seen any tutorials/blog posts on this that mention a speed issue, but I've not seen any that are specifically for mobile.

Comment: Why do you have to retrieve it via ajax? Why not just a dynamic response to the script/stylesheet request?

Comment: There is one very fast solution, which modernizr relies on
(
http://yepnopejs.com/
)
It can load resources (JS/CSS) conditionally. Maybe if you inspect the code, theres some chance of getting the right solution

Comment: TJ, the site is more like a web app than a simple web page. The data that's retrieved through AJAX is stored in local storage and retrieved from there instead of AJAX on subsequent page loads.

Comment: Yunzen, thanks for that. I'll look into how Modernizr does it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the size is a problem here. Have you try to compress : http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Does the lag happen once or multiples times ?

Comment: Yeah David, both the CSS and JS are minified.
The lag just seems to be a 1 or 2 sec thing on initial load before the scripts kick in.

Comment: Oh boy okay... only solution I see : load the files in different part.